# Selected data depending on rights

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a table with a list of report titles.
I need that for certain user roles and also depending on which microservice the call comes from, only those reports that are available for the role and service come to the front.
How can this be implemented?

It is also necessary to add all the roles and services to the database with the reporting table and write true and false to them, thereby determining access and on the back, according to these flags, decide who can do what.
Or are there better solutions for such purposes?

Comment: First of all its required to have a look how you designed your role and permission model. Could you please share that. It would great if you could share a minimum reproducible sample as well.